# How can I replace appendText on text area

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I want to replace all my text from text area when I click update instead of Adding some text again when I update

[image: heres my menu]

And heres my code for update event handler

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            txt_View.append(text_Sin.getText()+"\n");
            txt_View.append(text_Name.getText()+"\n");
            txt_View.append(text_Address.getText()+"\n");
            if(r_GenderM.isSelected()==true) {
                txt_View.append(r_GenderM.getText()+"\n");
            }
            else {
                txt_View.append(r_GenderF.getText()+"\n");
            }
            if(c_hSleeping.isSelected()==true) {
                txt_View.append(c_hSleeping.getText()+"\n");
            }
            if(c_hStudy.isSelected()==true) {
                txt_View.append(c_hStudy.getText()+"\n");
            }
            String combo = c_religion.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(combo.equals("Islam")) {
                txt_View.append("Islam\n");
            }else if(combo.equals("Christian")) {
                txt_View.append("Christian\n");
            }else if(combo.equals("Catholic")) {
                txt_View.append("Catholic\n");
            }
            else {
                txt_View.append("Atheist\n");
            }
            txt_View.append(text_Email.getText()+"\n");
            txt_View.append(text_Facebook.getText()+"\n");
            txt_View.append(text_Contact.getText());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the text, don't use `.append(...)` but rather simply use `.setText(...)` as per the [JTextArea Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) and [JTextArea API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)

Comment: thanks man appreciate it